# disabling AutoLayout in Xcode stops anything from displaying when I run

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I've disabled autoLayout because I had too many buttons and Xcode would crash consistently. But now when I run nothing will display

Comment: It would also be helpful to know a way to have it not crash and still have autolayout enabled

Answer (score 0):

First, It's obvious that disabling auto-layout is not what caused your view to not show up.
Second, it will be really helpful if you could add the crash log from the console. If we know what exception you're seeing, it will be easier for us to help.

Here are some things you can check:
1. Are all your subviews which are connected to IBOutlets and IBActions still connected to existing methods and variables? Go to "Connections Inspector" and make sure there is no small "x" which implies that a connection you created is now broken.
2. Is your view connected to the File's Owner?
3. Did you alter your AppDelegate file?

Comment: It's not so much that it's crashing but that most of the buttons simply aren't showing up. Also whenever I start Xcode, the same non-visible buttons have been resized to puny and shoved into the corner of the screen, I can then resize them and rearrange them but it seems to me that this doesn't stick during runtime.